# Flutter - Calling setState() without new data

Tags: flutter

I'm somewhat new to flutter and my question is more philosophical. When using setState(), is it bad practice to call it without using new data in the method? Ex: I call it like this:

```
setState({});
```

If there's a better way to refresh the build function or is this the best way?

Comment: No.
It will simply rebuild the widget tree.

Comment: It's considered code smell to not clearly indicate *why* you need the rebuild, which is most easily done by putting the state mutation inside the anonymous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` notifies that internal state of the object is changed, that reflect on entire subtree.

If you just change the state directly without calling setState, the framework might not schedule a build and the user interface for this subtree might not be updated to reflect the new state.

There are some other ways to trigger build method when data changes, but easiest one is `setState`() and for your purpose it is best.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use new data in your case. Your way of doing this is exactly how the Flutter team intended it to be used.